# Unable to generate TypeScript source maps with Rollup

Tags: javascript, typescript, babeljs, rollup, source-maps

I've tried a lot of things and nothing worked. I'm unable to get the original TypeScript source into my compiled JS files.

I've tried with and without Babel, and either worked properly.

Considering that this *might* be a problem with other app using my linked project, I checked directly into the generated source code and it does not contain any trace of the original TypeScript code to help debugging.

rollup.config.js:

```js
import { babel } from '@rollup/plugin-babel'
import resolve from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve'
import terser from '@rollup/plugin-terser'
import common from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs'
import { DEFAULT_EXTENSIONS } from '@babel/core'
import typescript from '@rollup/plugin-typescript'

const packageJson = require('./package.json')
const isDev = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development'
const isProd = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
const extensions = [...DEFAULT_EXTENSIONS, '.ts', '.tsx']
const tsconfig = isDev ? 'tsconfig.dev.json' : 'tsconfig.json'

export default {
  input: './src/index.ts',
  external: ['react'],
  output: [
    {
      file: packageJson.module,
      format: 'esm',
      sourcemap: 'inline',
    },
  ],
  plugins: [
    common(),
    typescript({ tsconfig }), // This is used now only to generate the .d.ts files
    resolve({
      extensions,
    }),
    babel({
      babelHelpers: 'bundled',
      extensions,
    }),
    isProd &&
      terser({
        maxWorkers: 4,
      }),
  ].filter(Boolean),
}
```

tsconfig.json:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "incremental": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "esnext",
    "jsx": "react",
    "noEmit": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "strict": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "declarationDir": "./dist/types",
    "declarationMap": true
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*.ts", "src/**/*.tsx"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "dist", "src/**/*.test.ts"]
}
```

.babelrc:

```json
{
  "presets": [
    "@babel/env",
    "@babel/preset-typescript",
    "@babel/preset-react"
  ]
}
```

package.json (in case the versions being used matters here):

```json
{
  "scripts": {
    "type-check": "tsc --noEmit",
    "types:dev": "tsc --project tsconfig.dev.json",
    "clear": "rimraf ./dist",
    "build": "npm run clear && rollup -c",
    "dev": "npm run clear && rollup -c rollup.config.js -w",
    "lint": "eslint . --cache"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.21.8",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.21.5",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.18.6",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.21.5",
    "@rollup/plugin-babel": "^6.0.3",
    "@rollup/plugin-commonjs": "^25.0.0",
    "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve": "^15.0.2",
    "@rollup/plugin-terser": "^0.4.3",
    "@rollup/plugin-typescript": "^11.1.1",
    "@types/react": "18.2.6",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.2.4",
    "rollup": "^2.79.1",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.2",
    "typescript": "5.0.4"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0"
  }
}
```

I'm using Node v18.15.0 and npm 9.6.2 on a macOS 13.3.1